# Вывод putchar у меня корректен?

Tags: c

Есть учебный маленький образец вывода посимвольного.
Программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
 int c;

 while (c = getchar() != EOF)
   putchar(c);
 system("PAUSE");
}
```

проблема, что она выводит вот такое:
[image]

так и должно быть?

Comment: внимательность и только внимательность, спасибо.

Comment: @steelhouse, пожалуйста, не забудьте принять ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)`